# Jenkins: sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory

Tags: jenkins, sshpass

I use Jenkins for CICD. After cloning the repository, I want to copy some file from cloned repository to a remote server using sshpass (scp).

```
sh """sshpass -p '$KEY'-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no scp *.json $UNAME@$PROD_IP:/home/test"""
```

But I get error in output:

```
sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory
```

What's wrong I'm doing ?

Comment: Does the /home/test directory exist in the target server?
Do you have any .json file under the root folder of the repository?

Comment: @ikerlasaga -  /home/test - this is home user directory. 2. I checkout git repo, and workspace dir contain this file.

Comment: Try running the same command from the jenkins server console but with some other test file. Then you might get a better understanding of the issue. Share the error code over here if there is any.

Comment: @ikerlasaga  -- the reason was that the keys were created from the home user, then I created new keys from jenkins user and everything worked .

Comment: nice, then add your solution as an answer over here so more people can see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search I found the answer. So, you need to switch to the jenkins user and create a pair of keys on his behalf and add to the remote server to which you need to access. Then add the private key into Jenkins credential and use.